# Maintenance page for Angular 5

Tags: angular

I made an Angular 5 application consuming REST service (Spring Java). The REST service and the web application are on different servers, in different networks.

I want to add a maintenance mode per my web application to enable not only when I'm going to work on the server side, but also when it is needed for other reason.
I want the Angular app intercept all requests and route them to a maintenance page.

I implemented this in this way. I created an AppConfig loaded at startup that loads a json file with some configuration of the app.

```
@Injectable()
export class AppConfig {

    public config: any = null;

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    /**
     * Use to get the data found in the file (config file)
     */
    public getConfig(key: any) {
        return this.config[key];
    }

    public load() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.http.get('assets/config.json').map(res => res.json()).catch((error: any): any => {
                console.log('Configuration file could not be read');
                resolve(true);
                return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
            }).subscribe((responseData) => {
                this.config = responseData;
                resolve(true);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

In the json file I've a property called "maintenance" that I check in my Http interceptor and I route to a specific page:

```
    @Injectable()
export class CustomHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  private jwtHelper = new JwtHelper();

  constructor(private injector: Injector, private authenticationService: AuthenticationService) { }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    let clonedRequest = null;

    const appConfig = this.injector.get(AppConfig);
    appConfig.load();


    if (appConfig.getConfig('maintenance').isactive === true) {
      this.authenticationService.maintenance()
    }
```

Again, it works but with a big disadvantage for my specific use case. The content of the json file is not reloaded when it changes on disk.
So, if I enable the maintenance mode, the redirect to the maintenance page works only if the user reload the website.
Instead my goal is to redirect the user as soon he make a http request.

I thought to reload the config.json each time a http request is made in the interceptor but I'm concerned about performance and if it is a best practice. Furthemore I've to add avoid the browser to cache that config file.

Some data: the json file is 1kb and it takes more or less 20-49ms to load each time. The Angular application is quite big and it makes tons of HTTP requests.

Is there a way to handle this use case in a good way avoiding to impact performances?

Comment: I have doubt on your case, when you switch to maintenance on your server side,  what is answering when he receive ajax request ?

Comment: Yes, if possible you could throw a specific error server side if maintenance mode is enabled, and catch that error in your interceptor

Comment: Yes, is exactly what have thinks first. If for any reason you can do this on your Spring app, i am sure you can configure tomcat (or whatever you use as webserver) to provide specific json when app is down. Another approch is to add Custom request Header to specify your app is down, no need to request again.

Comment: @Yanis-git Or when I'm working on the REST server, OR when for some reason the service must be offline because I'm working on the frontend or for administrative reasons (not technical).

Comment: @David That would be simple but is not enought. I doesn't catch the case when the REST server is offline and I want the maintenance mode on, or when the REST server is online and I want the maintenance mode on anyway.

Comment: Use websockets?

Comment: @David To read a json file in asset folder of the Angular app? I think you speak about websockets with the REST server. As described above I can't rely on the REST server to get the maintenance status.

Comment: You said that client won't know when the env.json file has changed. You could have a webserver for sockets, and push messages to your clients whenever the maintenance mode is activated. That way clients will know straight away that maintenance mode has been turned on, without having to make extra http requests

Comment: The points you made suggest that there should be a separate maintenance endpoint - API or just raw `maintenance.json`. It can be polled as often as needed when maintenance mode is on. And after it's off, you can re-read full config and stop polling maintenance endpoint.